# Number of files uploaded on server end (php) differs from the client side

Tags: php, ajax

HTML Form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fileinfo" id="myForm">

  <label>Your email address:</label>
  <input type="email" autocomplete="on" autofocus id="userid" name="userid" placeholder="email" required size="32" maxlength="64" /><br />

  <label>File to stash:</label>
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload[]" required />

  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload[]" required />

  <input type="submit" id="save" value="Stash the file!" />
</form>
```

I have used formdata to the best of my knowledge but I am not sure if I have done it right.
Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#save').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));

        var ins = document.getElementById('fileToUpload[]').files.length;
        console.log(ins);
        if (ins != 0) {
            fd.append("fileToUpload[][]", document.getElementById('fileToUpload[]').files[0]);
            fd.append("Email", $('#userid').val());

            for (var pair of fd.entries()) {
                console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
            }

            $.ajax({
              url: "upload.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: fd,
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
              }
            });
        }
        else{
            console.log("Nothing attached ");
        }


    })
</script>
```

In my upload.php file i am just trying to print the names. but i Am always getting count value as 3 whatever be the number of files uploaded on the front end, even if I don't upload any files at all, it gives the value 2.

```
 <?php
     $count = count($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
echo $count;
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  echo 'Name: '.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i].'\r\n';
}


?>
```

I am doing this for the first time. I have no idea where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: one thing that makes me curious is the `id="fileToUpload[]"`. I know we can do that in name, but I doubt it's valid as id.

Comment: If i just use fileToUpload then it gives an array at the php end becuase it expects a three dimensional array to access all files uploaded